# Autocomplete jquery duvida

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um script com autocomplete que eu queria que se o usuário digitasse uma palavra que não tem no script ele fosse redirecionado para uma url específica por exemplo aviso.html, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso, se puderem me ajudar desde já agradeço.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [
   {label: 'Google', value: 'http://google.com'},
   {label: 'Yahoo', value: 'http://yahoo.com'},
   {label: 'BMW', value: 'http://bmw.com'},
   {label: 'Bing', value: 'http://bing.com'}
  ];
  
     $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
   source: data,
   focus: function (event, ui) {
    $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
    return false;
   },
   select: function (event, ui) {
    $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
    window.location = ui.item.value;
    return false;
   }
  });
   });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="autocomplete" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para testar se não existe é melhor quando o utilizador submete o formulário com Enter. Nesse caso testa-se se o valor que o utilizador inseriu está no array data e caso não esteja altera-se o *url*.

```
$("#formulario").submit(function(){
   if (data.map(x=>x.label).indexOf($("#autocomplete").val()) == -1){
       window.location.href = "aviso.html";
   }

   return false;
});
```

Com o `data.map` mapeia-se o array de objetos num array so com as labels para depois com o `indexOf` saber se o texto está nesse sub-array. Quando o `indexOf` devolve `-1` indica que o elemento procurado não existe.

**Edit**:

Aplicando na página já existente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var data = [
            {label: 'Google', value: 'http://google.com'},
            {label: 'Yahoo', value: 'http://yahoo.com'},
            {label: 'BMW', value: 'http://bmw.com'},
            {label: 'Bing', value: 'http://bing.com'}
        ];

        $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
                window.location = ui.item.value;
                return false;
            }
        });

        //nova função aqui
        $("#formulario").submit(function(){
            if (data.map(x=>x.label).indexOf($("#autocomplete").val()) == -1){
                window.location.href = "aviso.html";
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="formulario"><!--Tem agora de ter aqui o formulario para se poder submeter-->
     <input id="autocomplete" />
<form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Boa noite Isac obrigado pelo seu retorno, eu tentei usar suas dicas mas infelizmente eu não consegui fazer funcionar, mesmo eu colocando uma palavra que não exista ele simplesmente não faz nenhuma ação.

Comment: No meu código assumi que que o campo de autocomplete esta dentro de um formulário com o id `formulario`. Assim como também assumi que seria colocado ainda dentro de `$(document).ready(function() {`. Confirme se tem dessa forma.

Comment: Na verdade eu chamo a função assim <input id="autocomplete" />

Comment: Show
Cara Muito obrigado... quebrei a cabeça tentando fazer isso funcionar...